# JSTL Tei Not Working

Tags: jsp, jstl

All the jstl tags which do not involve passing back a value using [Apache TagExtraInfo](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/apidocs/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tei/package-summary.html) (Tei) are working, but whenever I use a tag like `<c:forEach var="abc">...<%=abc%></c:forEach>` i am getting an error abc cannot be resolved.

---

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="<%=len%>">
<%str+=" Parameter type= " + (String)(tArray[i]) + " Parameter Value= "+ pArray[i];
logger.info(str);%>
</c:forEach>
```

Generates:

**

> An error occurred at line: 54 in the
>   jsp file:
>   /jsp/testutility/JMX/invoke.jsp i
>   cannot be resolved

**

Comment: What do you mean with "tei" here? Where did you learn about this? This is the first time I see/hear about this term in JSTL context.

Comment: tag extra info.. u can google that... it is a standard thing and is included in tld as tei...

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's not the correct way to do it, you should be doing this instead:

```
<c:forEach var="abc">
   ${abc}
</c:forEach>
```

`<%=abc%>` and `${abc}` are not the same thing. The first form is an old-style JSP scriptlet, the latter style is JSP Expression Language (EL), which works with JSTL.